How do I get my connection string in an Azure Durable Function
All my connection strings are added to my Azure Function app via the Azure Portal. In a http function, I'm able to access them through adding IConfiguration to my constructor:
private readonly ILogger<Update> _logger;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public Update(ILogger<Update> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _configuration = configuration;
}

That's how I access my connection string:
_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")

But how do I get access to them in a Durable Function? My startup Durable Function doesn't have a constructor (static class):
public static class MyFunction
{
    [Function(nameof(MyFunction))]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(MyFunction));
        logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
        var outputs = new List<string>();

        // Replace name and input with values relevant for your Durable Functions Activity
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));

        // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
        return outputs;
    }

    [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
    public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
        logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
        return $"Hello {name}!";
    }

    [Function("MyFunction_HttpStart")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("MyFunction_HttpStart");

        // Function input comes from the request content.
        string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
            nameof(MyFunction));

        logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

        // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
        // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
        return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
    }
}



All my connection strings are added to my Azure Function app via the
Azure Portal

May I know whether you put them in Application Settings section of your Azure Function app under Configuration blade? If so, it equals we put connection string in Values in local.settings.json like
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyConnectionString": "connection-string-here"
  }

Then we can use string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnectionString"); to get it.
If it's a seperate section like below,
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "SQLConnectionString": "<sqlclient-connection-string>"
}

since there's no construction method for static class, we can certainly use codes to new ConfigurationBuilder() and get the connection string.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
.Build();
string connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("SQLConnectionString");

By the way, we'd better to take a look at this section about Local settings file -> ConnectionStrings.

A collection. Don't use this collection for the connection strings
used by your function bindings. This collection is used only by
frameworks that typically get connection strings from the
ConnectionStrings section of a configuration file, like Entity
Framework. Connection strings in this object are added to the
environment with the provider type of System.Data.SqlClient. Items in
this collection aren't published to Azure with other app settings. You
must explicitly add these values to the Connection strings collection
of your function app settings. If you're creating a SqlConnection in
your function code, you should store the connection string value with
your other connections in Application Settings in the portal.

